# How to manipulate results from linq

Tags: c#, linq

i have a dropdownlist for year, problem is i want to check the latest year in the list and add 1.. so if the latest year in the list is 2011, i will manually add 1 for it to display 2012 also...  here is my code for your reference..

```
var b = (from a in sampleworker.getyear()
                 orderby a.Year
                 select new
                 {
                     a.Year
                 }
                 ).Distinct();

        b += int.Parse( (b.First()).ToString() ) + 1;
        drp_year.DataSource = b;
        drp_year.DataBind();
```

Thanks guys in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're getting an error on the b+= line because the Distinct() function is going to return an IEnumerable object.  Notice that you're trying to assign an integer to b on that line an yet on that same very line you are calling b.First() which is obviously something you can't do with an integer.

It looks like what you're really wanting is

```
    b.Add(b.First() + 1);
```

However, that won't work either.  You would have to do:

```
    var yearList = b.ToList();
    yearList.Add(b.First() + 1);
```

Then you can set your DataSource to that.  Also, what datatype is Year?  It's obviously not a string since you are having to use the ToString() method on it.  And I would think it's not an integer since you are using int.Parse() on it.  Which leads me to believe it's probably a DateTime, and if so why not use the methods that are already present on the DateTime object to manipulate the date instead of converting between types?

Edit: I adjusted the above code blocks after finding that Year is in fact an int.  Also, "select new { a.Year }" in his original code should be just "select a.Year".  See comments below for more info...

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Is that not what I explained from my first to second code block?

Comment: @BrandonMoore Hi, yearList.Add(int.Parse((b.First()).ToString()) + 1); have some errors.. 1)Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>.Add(AnonymousType#' has some invalid arguments 2)Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'int' to 'AnonymousType#1' Also year is an int..

Comment: @anonymous1110 That's why I asked what the data type of 'Year' is.  Without that information there's no way I could tell you exactly what you need to pass to the yearList.Add() method.

Comment: @BrandonMoore hi, the year is an int

Comment: @anonymous1110 You sure bout that? Your error says it can't convert *from* and int.  yearList would be a list of whatever type Year is, so if it's an int then you shouldn't be getting that error.

In the line that says "orderby a.Year" hover your mouse over 'Year' and tell me if it says it's an int or something else.

Comment: @BrandonMoore hi, it says, int tblblabla.year

Comment: Oops, I see... change "select new { a.Year }" to "select a.year".  That way it will just be an int type instead of an anonymous type.  You really don't need to use new {} when you are only selecting one value.

Comment: And FYI: if you are selecting more than one value (say 'select new { a.Year, a.Month }') then it's often easier to work with if you create a class and use that instead of an anonymous type.  So say you created a class called YearMonth that contained the properties Year and Month, then you would say 'select new YearMonth() { Year = a.Year, Month = a.Month }'.  It's really difficult to work with anonymous types if you have to pass them out of the procedure you created them in, so this makes it much easier.

Comment: Lastly, if it's an int then why the heck are you converting to a string and then parsing back to int???  Just say: 'yearList.Add(b.First() + 1);' (after you make the fix I mentioned two comments above)

Comment: @BrandonMoore: Thanks for pointing out my first comment was messed. One final thing, though: I'd suggest doing `yearList.Add(yearList.First() + 1);` to avoid performing a double-evaluation of `b`.